# Which are the favoured places to look for jobs?

Tags: careers

Apologies if this is not an appropriate question for this forum. I haven't been able to find a good answer elsewhere.

As per subject really, where do people go to look for academic statistical jobs (not data science)?

Full disclosure: We're recruiting, but struggling to get candidates.

Edit: I'm based in the UK, but will recruit internationally.

Comment: Harnham specialise in recruitment for data science in the UK as such they may be able to help with academic statistical jobs.

Comment: Have you already posted with the obvious organizations (e.g. the RSS, industry specific ones such as PSI if you are looking for biostatistics expertise etc.) and at the larger statistics departments (and other similar organizations such as MRCs)? Depending on the relevant career stage, there are also things like the RSS young statisticians meetings that often have a carreer fair component. It may of course not be easy to find experienced people at short notice, since some industries pay rather well compared to academia.

Comment: @Björn yes we have to some of the above. What is PSI? We're wondering whether we need to cast the net wider or maybe more focused (e.g. heads of dept at Unis)

Comment: PSI = statisticians in the pharmaceutical industry (I wonder why they did not want to use the acronym SPY...), see http://www.psiweb.org/.

Answer (score 1):

Note: This is mainly for USA.

For academic positions (tenure-track, visiting, postdoc, non-tenure track etc), UFL stats and Washington stats departments keep an up to date tab on the job postings. These are also free to post on I think. This is the general go-to for most people looking for jobs I know.

http://www.stat.washington.edu/jobs/

http://www.stat.ufl.edu/jobs/

The AMSTAT website has a job list, which I believe you have to pay for to post there. 
http://jobs.amstat.org/jobs

A lot of the applications are processed through MathJobs, so that is another good place to advertise. I am not sure it that costs any money.

https://www.mathjobs.org/jobs/jobs

As a graduate student, I have also received forwards from the department, when someone contacted the department heads with opportunities. So you could contact department heads personally.

Comment: Good point. I should have specified, I am UK based.

Comment: @ithinkiam Well, in that case, my answer is not as helpful. However, if you will recruit internationally, than the UFL and Washington websites are most definitely useful.